# VueJs - fetch data before redirect to page

Tags: javascript, html, css, typescript, vue.js

In `mounted` function i create an action which `fetch` data from Rest Api to my table in vuejs componeny

```
mounted() {
    UserService.getProjects().then(
      (response) => {
        this.isProject = true;
        this.projects = response.data;
      },
      (error) => {
        this.isProject = false;
      }
    );
}
```

but, when i click on my menu on route to this page, I'm redirected to this page in one second, but my data is still loading and at the beginning i have an empty table..., how to fetch data and then redirect to this page? thanks for any help

ps. i use `router-link` to navigate to another page

Comment: Have you tried using async and await in mounted hook?

Comment: @YashMaheshwari no, can you give an example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer your exact question, you can have a look at [Navigation Guards](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/navigation-guards.html#per-route-guard).

In your router, do something similar

```
const router = new VueRouter({
  routes: [
    {
      path: '/foo',
      component: Foo,
      beforeEnter: (to, from, next) => {
        UserService.getProjects().then(
          (response) => {
            // update store or some state
            next()
          },
          (error) => {
            // update store or some state
            next(false); //cancel or handle the error
          }
        );
      }
    }
  ]
})
```

But you probably don't want to delay the route transition until the data loads.  Instead you want to show a loading state until the data is ready.  So you would just handle that in your template and existing `mounted` function, the way you've done.

By blocking the navigation, you'd have to decide what to do when the data fails to load

Answer (score -1):

You can try using `async` and `await` on the mounted hook.

```
async mounted() {
    await UserService.getProjects().then(
      (response) => {
        this.isProject = true;
        this.projects = response.data;
      },
      (error) => {
        this.isProject = false;
      }
    );
}
```

Or you can also use Promise.

```
async mounted() {
    await Promise.all(
    UserService.getProjects().then(
      (response) => {
        this.isProject = true;
        this.projects = response.data;
      },
      (error) => {
        this.isProject = false;
      }
    );)
}
```

Comment: It's not work in my project :/ I think that I need to use beforeMount of somethine else

Comment: You can try one of three things: `beforeCreate`, `created` or `asyncData` in place of mounted hook